# Remove line feed if pattern

Tags: text-processing, csv

There is a CSV file like this:

```
1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th
"first-line
",2,3,4,5,6,7
"second-line
",2,3,4,5,6,7
"third-line
",2,3,4,5,6,7
"normal-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"forth-line
",2,3,4,5,6,7
"fifth-line
",2,3,4,5,6,7
```

It looks like the lines were broken by inserting a line feed just before the ending quote of the first column.
I want to remove that line feed.

I used the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129870/how-can-i-remove-a-line-feed-newline-before-a-pattern-using-sed), but it messes up if there is a correct line in the text like the header and the "normal-line".

**Is there a way to do this even with lines that are not broken?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New answer (October 2022), using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to strip the trailing whitespace from the first column:

```bash
$ mlr --csv put '$["1st"] = rstrip($["1st"])' file
1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th
first-line,2,3,4,5,6,7
second-line,2,3,4,5,6,7
third-line,2,3,4,5,6,7
normal-line,2,3,4,5,6,7
forth-line,2,3,4,5,6,7
fifth-line,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

To retain the original quoting:

```bash
$ mlr --csv --quote-original put '$["1st"] = rstrip($["1st"])' file
1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th
"first-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"second-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"third-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"normal-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"forth-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"fifth-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Note that we're using the column by name, not by position.

---

Old answer (June 2022):

Assuming none of your data contains the character `@` (change to some other unused character if that's not the case) and that you want to remove all embedded newlines:

```bash
$ csvformat -M @ file.csv | tr -d '\n' | tr '@' '\n'
1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th
first-line,2,3,4,5,6,7
second-line,2,3,4,5,6,7
third-line,2,3,4,5,6,7
normal-line,2,3,4,5,6,7
forth-line,2,3,4,5,6,7
fifth-line,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

This uses [`csvformat` from csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to reformat the CSV file to a data stream that uses `@` as the record terminator in place of the newline character.  Any newlines that are still in the data after that transformation are removed by the subsequent `tr` command.

The temporary record terminators are then changed back to newlines with a second invocation of `tr`.

Fields that need quoting will still be quoted in the output.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the quotes?

Comment: @Kazh If a field _needs_ quotes (because it contains embedded commas or quotes) it will be quoted. You may pass the end result through `csvformat -U 1` at the end to quote _all_ fields. Using `-U 2` is supposed to quote only non-numeric fields, but I've never managed to get that working.

Comment: @roaima Ah, cool, then I might actually sit down and write a bug report. The issue with bug reports is that I never know whether it's the tool or me that is doing the wrong thing :-)  Thanks!  I just have to test on some Linux system too, so that it's not a bug in an OpenBSD library.

Comment: @roaima [It's an open issue](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit/issues/938) since 2018.

Answer (score 1):

This will assume that the quoted text does not contain 6 commas.

```bash
awk -F, '
  NR == 1 {num_fields = NF}
  NF < num_fields {first=$0; getline; $0 = first FS $0}
  {print}
' file
```

Shorter still, perl: slurp the file whole, then remove the newline before quote-comma

```bash
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n(?=",)//g' file
```

Comment: +1 for the perl version. using a positive lookahead is better than the one I was about to post before I saw your answer: `perl -0777 -pe 's/\n(",)/$1/g' input.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Try als this `awk`- approach:

```
awk '{while (gsub("\"","&")%2) {getline T; $0 = $0 T}}  1' file
1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th
"first-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"second-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"third-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"normal-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"forth-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"fifth-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
```

It keeps appending next lines until we have an even count of double quote characters.

Answer (score 0):

`GNU sed` in extended regex mode (`-E`), we keep stitching the next record to the previous one , until the quoted fields balance.
This assumes no embedded quotes and carriage return (`\r`) characters in line endings.

```bash
sed -E ':a
  /^(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$/!{
    $!N;s/\n//;ta
  }
' file
```

---

Using `awk`, we taKe a different approach, where we keep a count of the current remainder of the number of commas

O E* O = E

E E* = E

```bash
awk -F '"' 'BEGIN {a[1]="\n"}
{ORS=a[!(n=(n+=(NF-1)%2)%2)]}
1' file
```

---

Output:-

```
1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th
"first-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"second-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"third-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"normal-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"forth-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"fifth-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) is really simple

```
mlr --csv clean-whitespace input.csv
```

to have

```
1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th
first-line,2,3,4,5,6,7
second-line,2,3,4,5,6,7
third-line,2,3,4,5,6,7
normal-line,2,3,4,5,6,7
forth-line,2,3,4,5,6,7
fifth-line,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for multi-char `RS`, `RT`, and `gensub()`:

```
$ awk -v RS='"([^"]|"")*"' '{ORS=gensub(/\n/,"","g",RT)} 1' file
1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th
"first-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"second-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"third-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"normal-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"forth-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
"fifth-line",2,3,4,5,6,7
```

The above just uses `RS` to isolate each `"..."` string and saves it in `RT`, then removes every `\n` in that string and saves the result in `ORS`, then prints the record.